# what will be the regex pattern for given rule?

Tags: regex, informatica

I have to write a regular expression for below :

1. Input string should contain more then 2 chars
2. Number should not be there in the given input string
3. it can be blank also.
4. There should not be any leading trailing spaces

I have tried below-

```
^[^0-9\s*]{2,}[^0-9\s*]$
```

But here one scenario is failing , if there is any space in string
like-

```
'ab cd e'
'ad c'
```

Can anyone please help me in this.

Comment: It also matches "a " and also trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You might use an optional group matching any char except a digit or whitespace at the start and at the end to match allow either an empty string or at least 2 characters.

```
^(?:[^\d\s][^\d\r\n]*[^\d\s])?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^\d\s]` Match any char except a digit or whitespace
  - `[^\d\r\n]*` Match 0+ times any char except a digit or newline
  - `[^\d\s]` Match any char except a digit or whitespace
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l9jHtl/1)